# NDepend Count, Average, etc.. reporting... aggregates. Possible? clean work arounds?

Tags: code-analysis, ndepend, trending, cqlinq

We have a huge code base, where methods with too many local variables alone returns 226 methods. I don't want this huge table being dumped into the xml output to clutter it up, and I'd like the top 10 if possible, but what I really want is the count so we can do trending and executive summaries. Is there a clean/efficient/scalable non-hacky way to do this?

I imagine I could use an executable task, instead of the ndepend task (so that the merge is not automatic) and the clutter doesn't get merged. Then manually operate on those files to get a summary, but I'd like to know if there is a shorter path?

Comment: What's wrong with producing the XML, and then using XSLT to filter it?

Comment: I would think this would be a major performance issue, 450+ assemblies, msbuild output, ndepend output, eventually fxcop and ncover output all in the same xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [defining a base line to only take account of new flaws](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/01/01/ensure-the-quality-of-the-code-that-will-be-developed-this-year.aspx)?

> what I really want is the count so we can do trending and executive summaries

Trending can be easily achieved with code queries and rules over LINQ (CQLinq) like: [Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html)

```
// <Name>Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)</Name>
// To visualize changes in code, right-click a matched method and select:
//  - Compare older and newer versions of source file
//  - Compare older and newer versions disassembled with Reflector

warnif count > 0 
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where
 !m.IsAbstract &&
  m.IsPresentInBothBuilds() &&
  m.CodeWasChanged()

let oldCC = m.OlderVersion().CyclomaticComplexity
where oldCC > 6 && m.CyclomaticComplexity > oldCC 

select new { m,
    oldCC ,
    newCC = m.CyclomaticComplexity ,
    oldLoc = m.OlderVersion().NbLinesOfCode,
    newLoc = m.NbLinesOfCode,
}
```

or [Avoid transforming an immutable type into a mutable one](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/Q_Avoid_transforming_an_immutable_type_into_a_mutable_one.html).